# Bash, MySQL, AWK -- Transforming a table to format a report

Tags: mysql, bash, csv, awk

I have a large database that contains data about embedded devices in the field.

I've built a MySQL query that outputs data in this format, called "/tmp/data.csv":

```
Device_Serial_Number, Device_Location_1, Device_Location_2, Date_1, Date_2
"3782D822", "Springfield, MA", "123 Maple Street", "2016-05-02 13:43:00", "2016-05-05 03:22:44"
. . .
```

The output is thousands of lines long. Note that an individual Device_Serial_Number value can appear multiple times, each with a unique set of "Date_1", "Date_2" values.

What I need to do is create separate .csv files for each value of "Device_Location_1". On that report, each unique value of "Device_Serial_Number" has only 1 row, but all values of "Date_1" and "Date_2" associated with that "Device_Serial_Number" on the entire spreadsheet will appear on that same row.

Example:

```
Device_Serial_Number, Device_Location_1, Device_Location_2, Date_1, Date_2, Date_1, Date_2, Date_1, Date_2
"3782D822", "Springfield, MA", "123 Maple Street", "2016-05-02 13:43:00", "2016-05-05 03:22:44", "2016-05-06 12:45:23", "2016-05-06 14:23:11", "2016-05-17 15:46:21", "2016-05-18 08:09:13"
```

Do do this I'm trying to use AWK within a Bash script. I have used a second MySQL query to get a list of unique device serial numbers, and have saved the results as "/tmp/devList.csv". I am attempting to read through each line of "devList.csv", and append a String variable with date strings that match that device list as found in "data.csv", then assign the Device_Serial_Number as the index on an associative array and the String of dates as the value.

Obviously this isn't working. I feel like this solution is way too complicated. Any help finding a working solution would be greatly appreciated.

```
awk -F, -v deviceList='/tmp/devList.csv' 'BEGIN { OFS=","; while (getline < deviceList) { device[$0]= "" } }
            {
                    dates = $4 "," $5 ","
                    holder = devices[$1]
                    newValue = holder dates
                    device[$1] = newValue
            }
            END {
                    for (i in device)
                            if (device[$i] != "")
                    print > "/tmp/test_output.csv"
            }' '/tmp/data.csv'
```

Comment: Could you upload a bigger example (not the whole thing) of data.csv and devList.csv?

Comment: Would it not be easier to let MySQL do the concatenation of dates for you - instead of columns for _date1_ & _date2_ use _group_concat(concat(date1,",",date2))_ and _GROUP BY loaction1, location2_ & order by those as well. Then AWK & BASH could then be used to split the file.

Comment: @PaulF I think that may be the solution. I assumed there was a way to make MySQL do the heavy lifting here, but I wasn't seeing it. Thank you! I'll update this thread if your solution gives me the output I need.

Comment: If you needed a header column for the multiple date1,date instances that would be more complicated as the query is returning a single field. Also if you needed all of the values surrounded by quotes when exported to CSV you may need to use _group_concat(concat(date1,'","',date2)) _ to add the inner double quotes - the export taking care of the two outer quotes around the single field.

Comment: Also, if you are going to parse csv using awk, I **strongly** suggest using [`FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) instead of `-F,` or embedded commas within a fields like `"Springfield, MA"` would completely mess up your field numbering. e.g. `$4` becomes `$5`...

Comment: @anishane is correct but bear in mind FPAT is is only available in GNU awk 4.0 or later. With other awks you need a `while(match(..)) substr(..)` loop.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for that addendum. I'm developing in the BSD AWK that Darwin ships with, so no FPAT for me. :/